# I want my discord bot to recognize my status and update my embed accordingly - Discord.Py

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
    elif message.content.startswith('!sirkris868'):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="sirkris868 :gem:", color=0x80a3dd)
        embed.add_field(name="KOS?", value="No", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Status", value="My status here", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Discord Tag", value="<@763786993058447431>", inline=False)
        #embed url thingey
        embed.set_image(url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/810062041960153108/810208599527129129/rqKso4V0ogQAAAAASUVORK5CYII.png')
        embed.set_footer(text='Designed by axb#0001')
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
status=message.guild.get_member((await bot.application_info()).owner.id).status
if status==discord.Status.online:
    status='Online'
elif status==discord.Status.offline:
    status='Offline'
elif status==discord.Status.idle:
    status='Idle'
else:
    status='Do Not Disturb'
```